# two people take turns throwing a die, what is the probability the second person beat the first one?

Tags: probability, dice

Two people take turns throwing a fair die, let $M_n$ denote the number of times during the first $n$ throws ($n$ is the total number of throws for both people) that the second person throw beats the preceding throw of the first person.

What is the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{M_n}{n}$ ?

What I tried:

The proportion of times the second throw beats the first person's throw  = $\frac{M_n}{n}$

By statistical definition of probability, we get

If total number of occurrences = $n$ ; number of occurrences of a particular event = $f$

Then, Probability of occurrence that event = $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f}{n}$

Therefore, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{M_n}{n}$ = Probability that the second person throw beats the preceding throw of the first person.

Is there any more steps to know more about the limit?

Comment: To get the probability that the second player beats the first, just compute the probability $p_t$ that they tie.  If they don't tie, then each player is equally likely to win.

Comment: is it (1-(1/6))/2 = 5/12 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.